# Extract array from array without loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-indexing

I am trying to extract part of an array from an array.

Let's assume I have an array `array1` with shape `(M, N, P)`. For my specific case, `M = 10`, `N = 5`, `P = 2000`. I have another array, `array2` of shape `(M, N, 1)`, which contains the starting points of the interesting data in `array1` along the last axis. I want to extract 50 points of this data starting with the indices given by `array2`, kind of like this:

```
array1[:, :, array2:array2 + 50]
```

I would expect a result of shape `(M, N, 50)`. Unfortunatly I get the Error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Sure I could also get the result by looping through the array, but I feel that there must be a smarter way, because I needed this quite often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a mask using a comparison of the values in array2 with an index range of the last dimension:

For example:

```
import numpy as np
    
M,N,P,k = 4,2,15,3   # yours would be 10,5,2000,50

A1 = np.arange(M*N*P).reshape((M,N,P))
A2 = np.arange(M*N).reshape((M,N,1)) + 1

rP = np.arange(P)[None,None,:]
A3 = A1[(rP>=A2)&(rP<A2+k)].reshape((M,N,k))
```

Input:

```
print(A1)

[[[  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14]
  [ 15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29]]

 [[ 30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44]
  [ 45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59]]

 [[ 60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74]
  [ 75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89]]

 [[ 90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104]
  [105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119]]]

print(A2)

[[[1]
  [2]]

 [[3]
  [4]]

 [[5]
  [6]]

 [[7]
  [8]]]
```

Output:

```
print(A3)

[[[  1   2   3]
  [ 17  18  19]]

 [[ 33  34  35]
  [ 49  50  51]]

 [[ 65  66  67]
  [ 81  82  83]]

 [[ 97  98  99]
  [113 114 115]]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast answer, that helped me a lot!

Comment: Clever way to make the mask

Answer (score 1):

Since your indices in each location are not aligned, you can create a mask or fancy index that extracts the desired elements. Since the extracted values are going to be flat, you will then have to reshape them.

Here is how you can create a mask:

```
K = 50
mask = np.zeros((M, N, P + 1), dtype=np.int8)
np.put_along_axis(mask, array2, 1, axis=-1)
np.put_along_axis(mask, array2 + K, -1, axis=-1)
mask.cumsum(axis=-1, out=mask)
mask = mask[..., :-1].view(bool)
```

We used the fact that `np.int8` and `np.bool_` have the same itemsize, and `np.cumsum` to propagate the initial mask position to the final in each axis.

The rest is fairly easy:

```
array3 = array1[mask].reshape(M, N, K)
```

You can avoid the extra element when constructing the mask by bypassing `np.put_along_axis` and using direct indexing with clipping where appropriate:

```
mask = np.zeros_like(array1, dtype=np.int8)
r = np.tile(np.arange(M)[:, None, None], (1, N, 1))
c = np.tile(np.arange(N)[None, :, None], (M, 1, 1))
clip_mask = array2 + K < P
mask[r, c, array2] = 1
mask[r[clip_mask], c[clip_mask], array2[clip_mask] + K] = -1
mask = np.cumsum(mask, axis=-1, out=mask).view(bool)
```

This is all pretty wasteful: to get an array of shape `(M, N, K)`, you are creating a boolean mask of size `(M, N, P)` along with some indexing arrays of size `(M, N, 1)`, another mask of size `(M, N, 1)` and then some masked versions of those indexing arrays. There's really nothing wrong with using `for` loops here, as long as you compile them, e.g. with cython or numba.

Comment: Thanks for reediting my question to make it more understandable and for explaining this "masked" approach so detailed!